# Apache Spark: broadcast join behaviour: filtering of joined tables and temp tables

Tags: apache-spark, hive

I need to join 2 tables in spark.
But instead of joining 2 tables completely, I first filter out a part of second table:

```
spark.sql("select * from a join b on a.key=b.key where b.value='xxx' ")
```

I want to use broadcast join in this case.

Spark has a parameter which defines max table size for broadcast join: ***`spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold`***:

> Configures the maximum size in bytes for a table that will be
> broadcast to all worker nodes when performing a join. By setting this
> value to -1 broadcasting can be disabled. Note that currently
> statistics are only supported for Hive Metastore tables where the
> command ANALYZE TABLE  COMPUTE STATISTICS noscan has been
> run. http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/sql-performance-tuning.html

I have following questions about this setup:

1. which table size spark will compare with autoBroadcastJoinThreshold's value: FULL size, or size AFTER applying where clause?
2. I am assuming that spark will apply *where* clause BEFORE broadcasting, correct?
3. the doc says I need to run Hive's Analyze Table command beforehand. How it will work in a case when I am using temp view as a table? As far as I understand I cannot run Analyze Table command against spark's temp view created via dataFrame.createorReplaceTempView("b"). Can I broadcast temp view contents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went ahead and did some small experiments to answer your 1st question.

**Question 1 :**

- created a dataframe `a` with 3 rows [key,df_a_column]
- created a dataframe `b` with 10 rows [key,value]
- ran: `spark.sql("SELECT * FROM a JOIN b ON a.key = b.key").explain()`

```
== Physical Plan ==
*(1) BroadcastHashJoin [key#122], [key#111], Inner, BuildLeft, false
:- BroadcastExchange HashedRelationBroadcastMode(List(cast(input[0, int, false] as bigint)),false), [id=#168]
:  +- LocalTableScan [key#122, df_a_column#123]
+- *(1) LocalTableScan [key#111, value#112]
```

As expected the Smaller df `a` with 3 rows is broadcasted.

- Ran : `spark.sql("SELECT * FROM a JOIN b ON a.key = b.key where b.value=\"bat\"").explain()`

```
== Physical Plan ==
*(1) BroadcastHashJoin [key#122], [key#111], Inner, BuildRight, false
:- *(1) LocalTableScan [key#122, df_a_column#123]
+- BroadcastExchange HashedRelationBroadcastMode(List(cast(input[0, int, false] as bigint)),false), [id=#152]
   +- LocalTableScan [key#111, value#112]
```

Here you can notice the dataframe `b` is Broadcasted ! meaning spark evaluates the **`size AFTER applying where`** for choosing which one to broadcast.

**Question 2 :**

Yes you are right. It's evident from the previous output it applies where first.

**Question 3 :**
No you cannot analyse but you can broadcast tempView table by hinting spark about it even in SQL. [ref](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-16475)

Example : `spark.sql("SELECT /*+ BROADCAST(b) */ * FROM a JOIN b ON a.key = b.key")`

And if you see explain now :

```
== Physical Plan ==
*(1) BroadcastHashJoin [key#122], [key#111], Inner, BuildRight, false
:- *(1) LocalTableScan [key#122, df_a_column#123]
+- BroadcastExchange HashedRelationBroadcastMode(List(cast(input[0, int, false] as bigint)),false), [id=#184]
   +- LocalTableScan [key#111, value#112]
```

Now if you see, dataframe `b` is broadcasted even though it has 10 rows.
In question 1, without the hint , `a` was broadcasted .

Note: Broadcast hint in SQL spark is available for 2.2

---

Tips to understand the physical plan :

- Figure out the dataframe from the `LocalTableScan[ list of columns ]`
- The dataframe present under the sub tree/list of `BroadcastExchange` is being broadcasted.

Answer (score 2):

Understanding for option 2 is correct.
You can not analyze a TEMP table in spark . Read [here](https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/20177)

In case you want to take the lead and want to specify the dataframe which you want to broadcast, instead spark decides, can use below snippet-

```
df = df1.join(F.broadcast(df2),df1.some_col == df2.some_col, "left")
```